# Set up a github repository for an existing LAMP set up

Tags: php, apache, git, github

I have a webserver setup using the standard linux, apache, mysql, php config and I currently don't have a way of doing revision control - I just backup the whole thing every now and then.  I'd like to set up a github repository for just the php and html files - basically everything in public_html.  Not really sure where to get started or how to approach it...  I guess I could just set up a git repository in the public_html folder itself but that doesn't seem ideal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a Git repository one level *above* public_html ( `git init; git commit -a` ). Simple and easy (Git only creates one folder wherever you create it); you don't need to use Github (which is a publicly accessible Git repository).

Comment: Yeah that was really all I needed to do.  I ended up creating a new folder to act as the repository and then I created another folder inside that and moved all my web stuff into it.  Then I just edited httpd.conf and pointed it there